# "No Keyword with name" error while using AutoIt Library Robot Framework

Tags: test-automation-framework, robotframework, robot

Got an error encountered "No keyword name" error in AutoIt Library Robot Framework. I installed the AutoIt Library by using pip install and it was successful.
I tried to automate input text in the Open Dialog Window to upload some file using AutoIt Library, but it won't run the keyword from AutoIt, it shows No keyword name.

Here is my code :

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation   This is the script for Create Sales Visit Repository
Library     AutoItLibrary

*** Test Cases ***

Input Text
    Send        C:\Users\ruela\Documents\Different images format\BMP.bmp
```

====================================================================

Or anything that can suggest uploading a file using robot framework, it's ok, since
the Choose File from selenium library cannot be used because of the open dialog window is not related to the web application.

Comment: Please show the code you have written

Comment: *** Settings ***
Documentation   This is the script for Create Sales Visit Repository
Library     AutoItLibrary



*** Test Cases ***

Input Text
    Send        C:\Users\ruela\Documents\Different images format\BMP.bmp

Comment: put that in your question please, whatever you have tried and what error you are getting

Comment: Is your AutoItLibrary library in [red.xml file](http://nokia.github.io/RED/help/user_guide/working_with_RED/red_xml.html)?

Comment: Sorry, my code in the comment shows not in the proper inline after I saved it. But that's the simple code every time the Open dialog windows pops up, Send keyword from AutoIt Library will perform and type the text, but it doesn't.

Comment: My AutoIt Library is not in the red.xml file. All files under AutoIt Library is in python file format.

Comment: ... just like Selenium is a Python file (not one actually, but that's a different discussion) in this case. Referenced libraries have to be imported into the project somehow, that's why you create a reference to them in red.xml. Read the link I shared, it's explained in more detail there.

Comment: @Rule put your error message also. A proper stack trace could give more information than you could imagine. When ever you post debugging issues keep the error log, your code, and the expected output.

Comment: Choose File            //input[@type="file"]          ${IMAGE_PATH}.     Hi Guys, I can now able to upload the file from the local desktop without  AutoItLibrary. I used the keyword Choose File from Selenium Library. See my syntax.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated:**

Even I faced the issue in recent versions of auto it and python:

**Fix:**

**Check your python architecture ( is it 32 or 64 bit)**

Just type python and see

[image]

**For 32:**

1. Open cmd in "**Run as administrator**" mode
2. run the command `pip install robotframework-autoitlibrary`
3. Now clone the autoit library source code: [nokia/robotframework-autoitlibrary](https://github.com/nokia/robotframework-autoitlibrary).
4. in the root directory run the below command: `python setup.py install` using cmd in admin mode

**to navigate to root directory use the command `pushd <filepath>' instead of` cd ` if cd doesn't work in cmd opened in admin mode.**

**For 64:**

1. Open cmd in "**Run as administrator**" mode
2. Now clone the autoit library source code: [nokia/robotframework-autoitlibrary](https://github.com/nokia/robotframework-autoitlibrary).
3. in the root directory run the below command: `python setup.py install` using cmd in admin mode

**to navigate to root directory use the command `pushd <filepath>' instead of` cd ` if cd doesn't work in cmd opened in admin mode.**

**You can install 64 bit python at:**

Install 64-bit python , the default version is 32 so you ahve to downlad the 64 bit download file from: [Python Releases for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)

and download **Windows x86-64 executable installer**

and install it.

Check if 64 bit is installed:

[image]

**Your code works fine for me :**

**Installed package :**

Open cmd in "Run as administrator mode" and run below command

```
pip install robotframework-autoitlibrary
```

**test.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation   This is the script for Create Sales Visit Repository
Library     AutoItLibrary

*** Test Cases ***

Input Text
    Send        C:\\Users\\ruela\\Documents\\Different images format\\BMP.bmp
```

**Ran as**

```
robot test.robot
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this. By the way, what python version did you use? I used Python 37, but I still got the "No Keyword" error once I tried you script to run on my side. I have installed the autoitlibrary using pip and was successful. I'm not sure if this is related to the specific version of python.

Comment: @RueL see if only one python is installed or even python 2 is present in your system

Comment: @RueL which ide are you using ? I ran it from cmd

Comment: I ran also in cmd. I just copy your code and follow the command robot test.robot

Comment: @RueL sorry for the confusion , i was able to fix the issue . The issue was due to auotIt.dll was not registering automatically

Comment: Please see the updated comment

Comment: @PDHide- How did you fix the issue? How can I fix the autoit.dll?

Comment: @RueL see the updated answer just download the autoit robotframework source code and instead of using pip , directly install the tool using `python setup.py install` if you get error like some module is missing then firsrtrun `pip install robotframework-autoitlibrary` and then the command.  Make sure you have opened the cmd as administrator , and to navigate to any folder use `'pushd <filepath>`  instead of `cd <filepath>`