# Importing test library 'AutoIt' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AutoIt' Error

Tags: selenium2, python, robotframework, eclipse, autoit

I am trying to file upload in modal form using robot/eclipse but its not working. I added autoit library to red.xml. Giving below error . 
Below is my code for file upload

```
Click Element   xpath=//*[@id="formProcessingImport"]
Win Activate  open (Explorer window)
Send   C:/Users/MyData.txt
```

Below is the structure and error I am getting.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please show your import statement ,

Comment: Library AutoIt                                                                                                          
Click Element   xpath=//*[@id="formProcessingImport"]
Win Activate  open (Explorer window)
Send   C:/Users/MyData.txt                                                                                                 But now I am planning to work with                                                                   
Choose File locator File Path But that is also not working.

Comment: I downloaded library from below address. https://code.google.com/archive/p/robotframework-autoitlibrary/downloads and now got  the module error has gone but still my robot framework script is not working..

Comment: THere is no setting section for your robotframework?

Comment: In setting section only I put Library  AutoIt. and as shown in image I put the path of init.py in red.xml.

Comment: How can you pass arguments to library ? in normal robot file the syntax is `Library     AutoItLibrary    5    ${True}`    where 5 is the timeout and ${True} is taking screenshot on failure. These arguments are mandatory

Comment: I am new to AutoIt. Can you elaborate share some link to get the example for how to upload the file in modal window upload in robot framework. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation   This is the script for Create Sales Visit Repository
Library     AutoItLibrary    5    ${True}

*** Test Cases ***
```

You should pass the above arguments to the Library , timeout and takescreenshot arguments are mandatory.

use `pip install robotframework-autoitlibrary` to install the library.

Refer below stackoverflow discussion for more information: [“No Keyword with name” error while using AutoIt Library Robot Framework](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/42312/40022).

The robotframework autoIt documentation is not much dependable, the documentation says that the library expects 3 parameters to constructor but when we check the init file we see that only 2 are required:
[robotframework-autoitlibrary/src/AutoItLibrary/__init__.py](https://github.com/nokia/robotframework-autoitlibrary/blob/master/src/AutoItLibrary/__init__.py).

To uplaod file:

File upload in Chrome browser

```
control focus  [CLASS:#32770; TITLE:Open]  ${EMPTY}  [CLASSNN:Edit1]
control send  [CLASS:#32770; TITLE:Open]  ${EMPTY}  [CLASSNN:Edit1]  C:\\File_Upload\\Test_Upload
control click  [CLASS:#32770; TITLE:Open]  ${EMPTY}  &Open
```

File upload in Firefox browser

```
control focus  File Upload  ${EMPTY}  [CLASSNN:Edit1]
control send  File Upload  ${EMPTY}  [CLASSNN:Edit1]  C:\\File_Upload\\Test_Upload
control click  File Upload  ${EMPTY}  &Open
```

Read more documentation, the class , title etc are find using autoit finder which will be available inside the 3rdpartytools in robotframework autoit folder. But in the above code you just have to change the file name to be uploaded

[image]

**Final Code:**

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation   This is the script for Create Sales Visit Repository
Library     AutoItLibrary    5    ${True}

*** Test Cases ***

Input Text
    Wait For Active Window    Open
    control focus    [CLASS:#32770; TITLE:Open]    ${EMPTY}    [CLASSNN:Edit1]
    control send    [CLASS:#32770; TITLE:Open]  ${EMPTY}    [CLASSNN:Edit1]    C:\\Users\\AdsKu\\Downloads\\MyData.txt
    control click    [CLASS:#32770; TITLE:Open]  ${EMPTY}   &Open
```

Comment: Hello, Some progress happened. 1. I clicked my 'Upload File Here' option using        
Click Element  xpath. File explorer opens and in the file name my files path appears. But now how to get that .txt file to nodal upload window and how to get close the file explorer.? Means how to click open button of explorer to send the file to upload.? I just use Send and my file path and not that Input text given to your example as it was giving an error,

Comment: Updated the answer , ones the open window comes up use the updated code. Change test upload with file you want  to upload

Comment: Nothing is happening only window opens as is which was opening initially. Even when I just used send atleast file was displaying in the file name where I just need to click open. But the updated code of controls is not doing anything and finally my browser with upload pop up and application is getting closed.

Comment: See the final code added, use that

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign if helpful

Comment: It looks fine code but facing new wierd issue where path in file name chaning like 
C;usersAdsKuDownloadMyData.txt
I tried with all combination
C:\Users\AdsKu\Downloads\MyData.txt and
C:\\Users\\AdsKu\\Downloads\\MyData.txt and
C:/Users/AdsKu/Downloads/MyData.txt 
But it turns into
C;usersAdsKuDownloadMyData.txt.
Please suggest.

Comment: C:\\Users\\AdsKu\\Downloads\\MyData.txt works i updated the code , refresh or clean eclispse and try again

Comment: Finally It Done... Thanks Bro...Answer Accepted.