# failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'robot.parsing.populators' error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, test-automation-framework, robotframework

[image]I was using python 3.6 for robot framework and selenium.
As my client wants to upgrade to python 3.7.1 we did that.
Now facing issue in running my automation scripts with the message as

```
failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'robot.parsing.populators'
```

Is it something as it is showing win32 when my system is 64/windows10
Please guide how to resolve this.
Thanks!

Sample code:

Hi, Below is my code. Which was working absolutely fine on python 3.6. But now issue here in 3.7.1

```
***settings***
Library    DateTime
Library   Selenium2Library
*** Test Cases ***
    Open Browser  ${URL}   ${BROWSER}
    Maximize Browser Window
    Set Browser Implicit Wait    5
    Capture Page Screenshot   ${PATH}BrowserOpened${TYPE OF FILE}
#Login to the application     
    Input Text  id=email   &{LOGINDATA}[email]
    Input Text  id=password   &{LOGINDATA}[password]
    Capture Page Screenshot   PasswordEnter${TYPE OF FILE}
    Click Element    xpath=//*[@id="btnSubmit"]
```

Comment: Python is telling you the external module you're trying to import, does not exist.  You need to add it using `pip install`, or simply downloading the source and using the `setup.py` for that package to install it.

Comment: Thanks but getting an error.
C:\Users>pip install robot.parsing.populators
Collecting robot.parsing.populators
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement robot.parsing.populators (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for robot.parsing.populators

Comment: @ADSKUL you have to do pip install robotframework ,

Comment: Robot is the root of robotframework

Comment: https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/autodoc/robot.html

Answer (score 1):

https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/autodoc/robot.html

robot class is the root of robotframework . So it seems like you don't have robotframework.

Just install robotframework using :

```
pip install robotframework --verbose
```

And see if it's installing correct python site package.

**Update**:

The author confirmed that the issue was with RIDE , reinstalling correct ride version fixed the issue .

Comment: Thanks but still getting error like this. [ ERROR ] Taking listener 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\RobotTempDir5297880248617435274\TestRunnerAgent.py:60880' into use failed: Importing listener 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\RobotTempDir5297880248617435274\TestRunnerAgent.py' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'robot.parsing.populators'
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: @ADSKUL can you add a sample python code

Comment: Hi, Below is my code. Which was working absolutely fine on python 3.6. But now issue here in 3.7.1 ***settings***
Library    DateTime
Library   Selenium2Library
*** Test Cases ***
    Open Browser  ${URL}   ${BROWSER}
    Maximize Browser Window
    Set Browser Implicit Wait    5
    Capture Page Screenshot   ${PATH}BrowserOpened${TYPE OF FILE}
#Login to the application     
    Input Text  id=email   &{LOGINDATA}[email]
    Input Text  id=password   &{LOGINDATA}[password]
    Capture Page Screenshot   PasswordEnter${TYPE OF FILE}
    Click Element    xpath=//*[@id="btnSubmit"]

Comment: Is it something which I have updated in question.

Comment: @ADSKUL could you show the testrunner.py ,how are you running this ?

Comment: How to check that ? C:\Users\adskul\AppData\Local\Temp\RobotTempDir8723711963901327353\TestRunnerAgent.py is the path.

Comment: Hi, I reinstall RIDE plugin and it starts working.Thanks. Please let me know from where and which version of Autoit library should I install.? Thanks

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/42312/40022 @ADSKUL refer this :)

Comment: Thanks, It worked and  Done!